# Error while importing gobblin gradle project into IDE

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, bigdata, gobblin

I am getting this error while I try to import the gobblin distribution into my IDE , I have tried both inteliJ and eclipse , not able to find any luck.
Below are the errors which I get when I try to import.
In Eclipse the error is:

```
*org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip'.
*
For InteliJ
*Cause: startup failed: build file 'C:\Users\sayyad.ghazi\Desktop\gob\gobblin-master\gobblin-restli\gobblin-throttling-service\gobblin-throttling-service-api\build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: .. @ line 1, column 1. ../../api.gradle ^ 1 error*
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because on Windows, Git can not create symbolic link file on non-admins mode. Symbolic link file is created as text file, containing a symbolic link.

Try the following command in Administrator Mode:

```
git clone -c core.symlinks=true <URL>
```

Then check the content of symbolic link file, such as "build.gradle" in your description. It should be the same as **the content of** "../../api.gradle", not just a symbolic link.

See [git-for-windows-wiki-Symbolic-Links](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-Links) for more details.