# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':gobblin-distribution:buildDistributionTar'

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle, gobblin

I am new to gobblin. I have downloaded incubator-gobblin-gobblin_0.11.0. while installing gobblin on windows 10 by following the instructions given [here](https://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-Started/) at execution of `./gradlew :gobblin-distribution:buildDistributionTar` 
I am getting below result.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':gobblin-distribution:buildDistributionTar'.
> Configuration with name 'dataTemplate' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

> java version "1.8.0_241"

If anyone know how to solve it please help.

Comment: Can you try the latest version - 0.14.0 https://github.com/apache/incubator-gobblin/releases,  or the version from the master branch ?

Comment: I have tried it. It gives ```startup failed:
  build file '/incubator-gobblin/gobblin-restli/gobblin-flow-config-service/gobblin-flow-config-service-api/build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: .. @ line 1, column 1.
     ../../api.gradle
     ^

  1 error```

Comment: On windows, an extra step is needed to turn on symbolic links when you check out a gobblin repo - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994595/error-while-importing-gobblin-gradle-project-into-ide . This is currently not reflected in the docs - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GOBBLIN-1021

Comment: This worked,but now I'am getting another error for `bin/gobblin cli run`
```WARN: HADOOP_HOME is not defined. Gobblin Hadoop libs will be used in classpath.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.gobblin.runtime.cli.GobblinCli```

Comment: Looks like this is a different problem, you can ask a separate question for it, if you have not found the answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

The getting started tutorial requires the latest version of the distro that can be obtained from the [release page](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gobblin/releases). As of early 2020, this version is 0.14